# Trying to understand below multithreaded program, but cant follow

Tags: java, multithreading

New to java, Trying to understand below multithreaded program. Any help is appreciated!!

The below program outputs 8.

when t1 starts and enters run method,  by the time it exists from run, count value is 4.

Now when t2 enters run method. I am confused  WHY the value of 'i' is not 5 , but count variable is 4 ? Since t1 and t2 shared common object "pt", shouldn't t2 pick up all the values from where t1 left.  I am confused? why is count and i variable treated differently?

```
 public class JavaProgramming {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            ProcessingThread pt = new ProcessingThread();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(pt, "t1");
            t1.start();
            t1.join();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(pt, "t2");
            t2.start();
            t2.join();
            System.out.println("Processing count=" + pt.getCount());
        }
    }

    class ProcessingThread implements Runnable {
        private int count;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                processSomething(i);
                count++;
            }
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return this.count;
        }

        private void processSomething(int i) {
            // processing some job
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

new `i` is created every time you run loop, also you're explicitly assigning `i=1`, so `i` cannot be 5 when you run it second time, it even does not exist before and after loop (the only time `i` is 5 is just before loop finishes)

first time you execute `run`, loop's body executed 4 times (i=1,2,3,4 = 4 times), this is why `count` is incremented 4 times, this is why it is 4

Comment: In other words, `i` is a local variable.  ALL local variables get created anew each time you enter the method where they're defined (doesn't matter how, a new thread or the same one).  Whereas `count` is an instance variable, so it persists between calls to `run()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `run()` method is gone through 4 times bu each thread, not 5, i.e. **for** the following values of `i : 1, 2, 3, 4`. Since your exit condition on `for loop` is `i<5`, and not `i<=5`, when entering the `for loop` for the fifth time, since condition `i<5` is no longer met, `for loop` is immediately exited.